# Interpolation on grid using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I am completely new to QGIS.

The problem I have is finding away to interpolate the data on the grid. I'm not sure if you can do it or not.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Data I have at the moment is a Join attributes by location with a boundary and pointers.

Link to data I have https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1I_-NO2PjTuJOln3yACh2AhhlMZXKG099?usp=sharing

Image 1

[image] [image]

This is the data I would like to interpolate for example phkcl to all the other grid blocks with out a point

here is an example of data that does not have a point

image 2

[image] [image]

So the end result I would like to have is to interpolate the data from the points/grid blocks I have into the grid blocks with Null data, so every grid block has data inside them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The solution: the principles

You can do this creating an interpolated raster out of the points and then get the raster (pixel) value inside of each cell. There are several raster interpolation methods available in QGIS, one being GRASS [v.surf.rst](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.surf.rst.html). Others include [QGIS native interpolation tools](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) like IDW Interpolation, TIN Interpolation or Heatmap (Kernel density estimation).

All are available in the Toolbox (`Menu Processing > Toolbox`), typing the name in the filter field. Which tool/algorithm to use depends on what kind of data is represented and what you want to achieve with interpolation.

See the examples below: depending an what interpolation-algorithm and what parameters you use, the result looks different. Using IDW with the settings I used, the results are closer to local values of the input points, thus representing better local anomalies whereas `v.surf.rst` creates a smoother overall output, but "smoothing" out local aberration.

---

### How to do it with your data - step by step guide

I describe how you can achieve that using your data. Here, I show it using v.surf.rst. Forst, create a raster that masks everythin outside the polygons - you only want an interpolation inside the polygons (grid):

1. Run `Menu Raster > Conversion > Rasterize`, set `Mega_build_try` (grid) as input. Set `A fixed value to burn` to `1` and`Assign a specific nodata value to output bands` to `0`. For Width/Horizontal as well as Heigth/Vertical resolution set a value, e.g. 1000. Set `Output raster size units` to `Pixels`. For output extent, select the extent of your polygon layer:

   [image]
2. Run `Menu Processing > Toolbox > v.surf.rst` and make the following settings (see screenshot below):

- Use your points as input layer
- Use the attribute you want (e.g. `phkcl`) as `Name of the attribute with values to be used for approximation` (the value to be interpolated)
- For `Name of the raster map used as mask`, use the output of step one: the black/white raster as we want to create only interpolated values in the black areas/inside the grid polygon
- `v.surf.rst` can output several different rasters, we just need one, the first one: `Interpolated RST` - check the box next to this and uncheck all others! Otherwise, calculation will take longer and you'll get results you don't need.

  After running the tool, you get an interpolated output raster in grayscale. On the screenshot, I assigned a Viridis color ramp to see the distinctions better:

  [image]

3. Now you can get the value of the interpolated raster for each cell of the grid, respectively for the centroid of each cell. You can use QGIS expressions with Field Calculator to create a new attribute field for the interpolated value for each cell. Use this expression: `raster_value( 'Interpolated RST', 1, centroid($geometry))` where `Interpolated RST` is the name of the output layer of step 2.

   *Each grid cell is labeled, using the expression from above (with an additional `round()` function to reduce number of decimals). You see the value of red points, labeled in black and interpolated value of centroid of each grid cell, labeled in red:*
   [image]

---

### IDW Interpolation

See here how the result differs, using another algorithm:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me.
I was wondering if you know how to add the IDW Interpolation values into the Mega_build_try Attribute Table?
I found the Raster layer unique values report to extract the data but I'm not sure how to add it into the Mega_build_try Attribute Table

Comment: Field Calculator to create a new attribute field